# How to import record from csv file in c# Enum

Tags: c#, csv, enums

How can I load a CSV file into Enum in c#, I want to import data from csv file and put this data into number of enums based on number of lines (record)  in csv file. 
This is my Csv file: 
[image: Csv file]

I want to import this data in 4 enum such as i create this enums by my hand:

```
enum Name { Sam, John, Nodir };
enum Job { M.S, M.R, M.d};
enum Name { 5000, 7000, 9000};
enum Name { Some, Data, Info};
```

How i can make that? Can anyone give me please a link or piece of code

Comment: You shouldn't really be using enums for this, Either a dictionary or a list depending on how you intend to use it later and if you intend to keep the records associated to one another.

Comment: Enums are created at design time.

Comment: *Why* do you think you need enums? What are you really trying to do? Enums are useful only to represent *a limited, predefined, small set of values*. Your data is none of these things - in fact it's the exact opposite.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, You are right but i use enum because i will compare this data by another existing enums to check some values.

Comment: @mbugr You don't need enums to do that. Just check the values against the enum names using [Enum.IsDefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.110).aspx), [Enum.GeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) or Enum.GetNames. Sounds that you really wanted to ask how to compare a string value to an enum's name? That's what's called [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - asking about supposed solutions to a problem, not the actual problem itself.

Comment: Better yet, create a table of reference values, or add them to configuration, so you *don't* have to recompile each time you need to add another lookup value

Answer (score 1):

```
var csv = "2,1,1,2,2,1";

List<Events> EventList = new List<Events>();

foreach (string s in csv.Split(','))
{
    EventList.Add((Events)Enum.Parse( typeof(Events), s, true));
}
```

Comment: It is best to explain *why* your solution works, rather than simply placing your code here.